# error during mongo db.shutdownServer()

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I got the following error when I try to shutdown mongodb in my VM Ubuntu.

I am running 12.10 Ubuntu headless server.

The current Mongodb Shell Version  is 2.0.6

```
use admin
switched to db admin
> db.shutdownServer()
Tue Dec 10 14:17:03 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Tue Dec 10 14:17:03 query failed : admin.$cmd { shutdown: 1.0 } to: 127.0.0.1
server should be down...
Tue Dec 10 14:17:03 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1
Tue Dec 10 14:17:03 reconnect 127.0.0.1 ok
Tue Dec 10 14:17:03 Socket recv() errno:104 Connection reset by peer 127.0.0.1:27017
Tue Dec 10 14:17:03 SocketException: remote: 127.0.0.1:27017 error: 9001 socket exception [1] server [127.0.0.1:27017] 
Tue Dec 10 14:17:03 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Tue Dec 10 14:17:03 query failed : admin.$cmd { getlasterror: 1.0, w: 1.0 } to: 127.0.0.1
Tue Dec 10 14:17:03 Error: error doing query: failed shell/collection.js:151
```

What should I do?

My reason for trying to shut it down is because I want to update to mongo 2.2.

Please advise.

Comment: i had never seen this message until now, when I had two installs one with brew and one the default one. Even after removing the one installed with brew, I was still receiving the message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the messaging is confusing, this is actually expected behaviour if you shutdown via the `mongo` shell. Since you ran the `db.shutdownServer()` command through the `mongo` shell it can no longer connect to the server and this is essentially indicating the shell has been disconnected.

The `mongo` shell tries to automatically reconnect when you hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, which results in the messages like "trying to reconnect ...".

There is an open issue to improve this behaviour/messaging if you'd like to upvote/watch it: [SERVER-5467](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5467).